# Where can I find PrimitiveArrays in Guava?

Tags: guava

I was using `com.google.common.collect.PrimitiveArrays` from Google Collections, however I cannot find it in Guava, was it renamed? Where can I find it?

Comment: Looks like you were using one of the snapshots from before Google Collections 1.0, so unfortunately it can be a pain to upgrade. At least, once you're on Guava, things will be much smoother: an API not marked "beta" will only be removed after a lengthy deprecation (I consider 18 months to be lengthy), and one marked "beta" will at least get one release of deprecation before being yanked, so by single-stepping your upgrades you should always get guidance on how to adapt to the changes.

Comment: Kevin, could you take a minute and paste this into http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Faq ? Just for easier recyclability :)

Comment: why, it is on the FAQ!  FAQ link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=guava&sort=votes&pagesize=50

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are classes in `com.google.common.primitives` such as `Ints`, `Doubles`, `Floats`, etc. that I think have the functionality of the old `PrimitiveArrays` class (and then some).